# jQuery Isotope; integrating a loop/circular function on horizontal layout?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am building a website for a client who'd like their content displayed in a horizontal grid layout.  I will be using Isotope to do this since I am most familiar with the script.  I've used it many times to do vertical and horizontal layouts.

My question is, because I couldn't find anything on here or on the developer's site, is there a way to add a way for the content to loop when you've reached the end of scrolling?

Ideally, like those slideshows that just loop in a circular motion, when a viewer reaches the end of the horizontal layout it would loop and start back from the beginning.  I currently don't know any way of doing this and adding custom functions/scripts isn't my strongest point.

Has anyone seem or implemented this featured to Isotope, or could they possibly point me in a good direction?  If you have any examples, or possibly some snippets of code that could help, that would be great.

Comment: Show us how do you use **Isotope**, what options, and to manipulate what kind of elements...

Comment: I haven't begun to code anything yet, so I have no code.  But I would use isotope similar to the examples from the developer's site.

Comment: Do you wan't this [kind of result](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/infinite-scroll.html)? An infiny scrolling... Else, give me a link to the best example of that you wan't.

Comment: Not infinite as in loading new posts, infinite as in looping from post the last post to the first.  Let's say I have 10 child elements to my wrapping div that is isotope.  after the 10th item, the first item follows.  continuously looping.